# Как увеличить размер объекта вверх и сохранить его форму?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть [следующий CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/n484qzka/47/):

```
.tank {
    position:relative;
    width:12px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#444;
}
.tank:before {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:#666;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:-2.5px;
}
.tank:after {
    width: 12px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color:#444;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    border-radius: 6px / 2.5px;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:15.5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Когда я добавляю его на свою карту, это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я пытаюсь увеличить размер с помощью CSS, то размер корректируется назад (он идет вниз по карте, а не вверх).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался исправить это с помощью `position` и `height`, но все равно получил тот же результат.

**Вопросы:**

- Как мне отрегулировать объект в сторону увеличения
- Сохранить цилиндр той же формы (основание и верх должны быть
  закругленными).
- Можно ли иметь "динамическую регулировку", скажем, `<div class = "tank-20"> </div>` (означает высоту 20) и `` (= 80 в высоту ).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n484qzka/47/)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to increase size of object upwards and maintain its shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63960884/7394871) от участника  [@ProcolHarum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11986167/procolharum).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63960884/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обновить свой код, как показано ниже:

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block; /* this will make them stay at the bottom */
  margin: 40px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  height: var(--w,180px);
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
}

.tank:before,
.tank:after{ 
  border-radius: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.tank:before {
  background-color: #666;
  top: 0;
}

.tank:after {
  background-color: #444;
  bottom:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tank"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:100px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:200px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:80px"></div>
```

Еще одна идея. Наведите курсор, чтобы увидеть растущий эффект:

```css
.tank {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 40px 10px;
  width: 120px;
  /* big height here to illustarte, 
    you don't need it if you will place your element using position:absolute */
  height: 300px; 
}

.tank:before,
.tank:after{ 
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 60px / 25px;
}
.tank:after {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(50% 50%,#666 98%,transparent 100%) top/100% 50px no-repeat, 
    #444;
  bottom:25px;
  height:var(--w,180px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.tank:before {
  background-color: #444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.tank:hover::after {
  height:calc(1.5*var(--w,180px));
}
```

```html
<div class="tank"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:100px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:200px"></div>
<div class="tank" style="--w:80px"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961708/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>